# Arrays compare in golang

Tags: go

I need to compare 2 arrays of uint32, something like this

```
   func in(a uint32, list []uint32) bool {
        for _, b := range list {
            if b == a {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
for n := 0 ;n < len(a); n++ {
        fmt.Println(in(a[n], b))
    }
// a and b []uint32
```

but I think it is not the most optimal way

Comment: so it should only return `true` if the arrays are exactly the same including their order?

Comment: If you need to not take into account the order - sort them first, then compare with `==`. It would be logarithmic, not polinomial.

Comment: `[]uint32` is **not** an array, it is a slice.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `==` if you are actually using arrays?

> https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators
>
> Array values are comparable if values of the array element type are comparable. Two array values are equal if their corresponding elements are equal.

If you are using slices, you can use `reflect.DeepEqual`.

But, from your code, it seems like you should look into https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/container/intsets

Then, you create your two `intsets.Sparse` and could then do:

```
func main() {
    s1 := intsets.Sparse{}
    s2 := intsets.Sparse{}
    s1.Insert(1)
    s1.Insert(2)
    s1.Insert(3)
    s2.Insert(1)
    s2.Insert(2)
    //s1:{1,2,3}
    //s2:{1,2}
    fmt.Println(s1.SubsetOf(&s2), s2.SubsetOf(&s1))
    //false, true
}
```

which will ignore duplicates, but let you know if s1 is a subset of s2, meaning every element in s1 exists in s2.